# VideoView is not properly rendered after Dialog's keyboard disappeared

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I simplified my problem to the smallest example when it can be reproduced.

So:

- 1 activity with VideoView and ImageView.
- After clicking on ImageView AlertDialog is showed.
- AlertDialog have 1 EditText field.
- I touch this EditText and standard Android keyboard is showed.
- Close keyboard.
- Close dialog.

**Problem:** VideoView's borders (black rectangle) were extended and thus ImageView is not showed anymore.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Activity act = this;
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoView.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/s1ep01.mp4");
    videoView.requestFocus();
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save translation", null);
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/videoView1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think it is safe in this case to add to your activity in the manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`.

Answer (score 3):

as a Temporary solution, i created a Runnable that makes the VideoView Invisible, then makes it Visible after 200 milli seconds :

```
// Hide the VideoView
videoLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// create a handler to handle the delayed runnable request
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // After the 200 millis (which are passes as a second parameter to this postDelayed() method in the last line of the code, this handler will invoke the following method :

        // run on UI so you can set the Visibitity of the UI elements
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
            public void run() {videoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}    // make it visible again
 });
    }
}, 200);    // this is the second parameter which decides when this handler will run it's run() method
```

hope this temporary solution helps for now

call this methods when your keyboard is hiding, alike on ENTER key, or when you touch a certain view outside the keyboard to hide it ... but dont put it in the onTouchEvent() of the activity or in the onUserInteraction so not to keep flashing

Comment: 1- Read my comment on the question. 2- I think calling `requestLayout();` is enough instead of posting a delayed runnable.

Comment: but if it adjusts nothing, my edit text will be covered by the soft input keyboard !? ... i'll try the requestLayout() instead of posting a runnable ... you mean using it in the same situations instead ... thats what i understood from you

Comment: Just play around with the `android:windowSoftInputMode`. I think this might do the job for you: http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/10/softkeyboard-problem-with-tabhost-on.html

Comment: @SherifelKhatib as i told you, adjustNothing hides the Edit text, and requestLayout() does nothing, either calling it from the Layout wrapping the VideView, or calling it from the the VideView itself

Comment: Actually, I think you did not click the link :P. It advices: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Comment: i clicked and tried, it is the same as adjustNothing (in effect) :)